# Highcharts Drill-up button

Tags: highcharts, drilldown

I have inherited a chart with 2 levels of drill-down. Drill-down is achieved via a click event, returning to the start from the deepest level:

```
click: function () {
    var drilldown = this.drilldown;
    var options;
    if (drilldown) { // drill down
        options = {
            'title': drilldown.title,
            'subtitle': drilldown.subtitle,
            'name': drilldown.name,
            'categories': drilldown.categories,
            'data': drilldown.data,
            'type': chartType
        };
    } else { // restore
        options = {
            'title': title,
            'subtitle': subtitle,
            'name': name,
            'categories': categories,
            'data': data,
            'type': chartType
    };
}
setChart(options);                                }
```

(see http://jsfiddle.net/Scrooge/o3bcLwqz/ for full chart)

My question: How can I add a drill-up button, so I can go from level 1 to level 0, without having to drill all the way down?

Comment: Well, just show button, when you drilldown, and hide that button when you restore chart. Of course you need to implement whole logic behind that (like storing actual level, and parent in case of button click). Or you can use Highcharts plugin for drilldown, see [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#drilldown). ;)

Comment: Thanks  Paweł. I did a re-write using the drilldown plugin - works well for a column chart (http://jsfiddle.net/Scrooge/qtdykr4r/8/), but the pie chart version (http://jsfiddle.net/Scrooge/w4xntLk5/6/) has serious problems. Any ideas why?

Comment: Right, it looks like a bug - I found cone related to this issue, see [this](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3534). Feel free to ping devs to fix that issue ;)